# How to convert varchar to datetime format and apply a condition

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have a ORACLE table where in one of the column the date time is stored as a text in the below format

```
 16:22:38:0570 14 SEP 2022
```

I would like to know how to parse this value as a proper datetime and apply a condition on SELECT.

Assume below is the table

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TEST_TABLE (
  DID number(10) NOT NULL,
  DTEXT varchar2 (50),
  CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY (DID)
);
```

Contains below records.

```
DID  DTEXT
1    13:25:58:0570 15 SEP 2022
2    10:20:38:0270 15 SEP 2022
3    16:22:38:0570 14 SEP 2022
4    02:19:18:0370 14 SEP 2022
5    03:29:14:0330 13 SEP 2022
```

How can I select the records that are older than or equal to 14th September 2022?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TO_TIMESTAMP()` conversion with the following format mask

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(dtext,'HH24:MI:SS:FF DD MON YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
  FROM dual
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/6wkgW6fj)</kbd>

Comment: Based on your answer I framed the query as below `SELECT * FROM MY_TEST_TABLE WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(DTEXT,'HH24:MI:SS:FF DD MON YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') <= TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-09-14 23:59:59.999','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')`

Comment: @Malaiselvan: You can probably simplify this to `< DATE '2022-09-15'`. On a side note: Writing everything in uppercase lessens readability. See how Barbaros Özhan writes keywords in uppercase and table and column names in lowercase. This is much better.